# MapReduce to determine credit balance in a ledger

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a transaction ledger, where debit and credit transactions are stored. I needed to determine credit balance for the `account : 121`. I found a way to do it. Only, I don't understand half of what I did, and why this works.

```
var dummyschema = mongoose.Schema({
  account: Number,
  refAccount: Number,
  credit: Boolean,
  amount: Number,

});

var dummyTx = mongoose.model('dummyTx', dummyschema);

var c = {};
c.map = function() {emit("credit", this.amount);};
c.reduce = function(key, values) { return Array.sum(values);};
c.query = { account : 121, credit: true };
c.out = {inline:1};

var d = {};
d.map = function() {emit("debit", this.amount);};
d.reduce = function(key, values) { return Array.sum(values);};
d.query = { account : 121, credit: false };
d.out = {inline:1};

dummyTx.mapReduce(c, function (error, credit) {
  dummyTx.mapReduce(d, function (err, debit) {
    console.log(credit['0'].value - debit['0'].value);
  });
});
```

Could you please tell me if there's a better way to do this. I read the MapReduce documentation entry, but it mostly flew over my head. If you just give me the code, I'll try to understand it.. although an explanation would be so much more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach you could take is using the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)**. The aggregation pipeline that achieves the desired result is one where you have a [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) operator that filters the documents in the collection by a given query criteria, in your case that would be documents with the account number 121.

Further down the pipeline is where the magic happens. The [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator reshapes the documents by adding an extra field, balance which would be used to calculate the total for that account. The balance field would use the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) and [**`$multiply`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/#exp._S_multiply) operators to get its value based on the condition that if the credit value is false then it gets it value from the amount multiplied by -1, else it would be the default positive amount value.

After the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) pipeline step is the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator stage which then calculates the total aggregated balance when the documents are grouped by the account number field, this makes use of the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#grp._S_sum) operator which adds up all the balance values.

Thus in the end you end up with the following aggregation pipeline:

```
db.dummyTx.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": { "account": 121 }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "balance": {
                 "$cond": [ 
                    {
                        "$eq": [ "$credit", false ]
                    }, 
                    { 
                        "$multiply": [ -1, "$amount" ] 
                    }, 
                    "$amount" 
                 ]
            },
            "account": 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$account",
            "total": {
                "$sum": "$balance"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Let's demonstrate this by adding some test documents to the dummyTx collection:

```
db.dummyTx.insert([
    { account: 121, credit: true, amount: 5 },
    { account: 121, credit: true, amount: 2 },
    { account: 121, credit: false, amount: 10 },
    { account: 121, credit: false, amount: 2 }
])
```

The above aggregation pipeline will give the following result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 121,
            "total" : -5
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

To implement this in Mongoose, you can use the **[aggregation pipeline builder](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate)** as follows:

```
Model.aggregate()
      .match({"account": 121})
      .project({ "balance": { "$cond": [ 
                    {"$eq": [ "$credit", false ]}, 
                    {"$multiply": [ -1, "$amount" ]}, 
                    "$amount" 
                 ]},
            "account": 1})
      .group({"_id": "$account","total": {"$sum": "$balance"}})
      .exec(callback);
```

-- **UPDATE** --

If you still prefer the Map-Reduce option, you could try the following **[Map-Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)** operation which uses the same concept as above; your map function would emit a key-value pair that includes a modified key `balance` based on the criteria that if the credit value is true then the `balance` field would have a positive `amount`, else it would be a negative.

The reduce function then collects and condenses the aggregated data by reducing the values array to the sum of its elements. MongoDB then stores the results in a collection `outputTx`. Thus your Map-Reduce operation would look like this:

```
var d = {},
    map = function() {
        var balance = this.credit ? this.amount : -1 * this.amount;
        emit("balance", balance);
    },
    reduce = function(key, values) { return Array.sum(values);};
d.query = { account : 121 };
d.out = "outputTx";

db.dummyTx.mapReduce(map, reduce, d);
```

Querying the output collection `db.outputTx.find({})` would give the result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "balance",
    "value" : -5
}
```

Comment: @SylvainLeroux You can say that again!

Comment: Thank you so much. The aggregation framework does appear more readable, and as I read the documentation, i understand that it is much more versatile! I think I'll spend some time reading up on this :D

Comment: @amingilani No worries. The aggregation framework indeed is a powerful tool if you know how to apply the various aggregation operators to achieve the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) is a more readable (and probably more efficient) way to achieve the desired result:

I let you adapt that to mongoose, but from the mongo shell:

```
db.dummyTx.aggregate([
    {$match: {account:121}},
    {$project: { credit: {$cond: ["$credit",
                                  "$amount", 
                                  {$subtract: [0, "$amount"]} ]} }},
    {$group: { _id: "$account", balance: {$sum: "$credit"}}}
])
```

- the [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) stage keep only the account #121;
- the [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage will synthesize a field `credit` whose value is `$amount` in case of credit, `-$amount` in case of debit;
- finally, the [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) stage will sum (positive or negative) credits to calculate the total balance.